# as400 error code C100 101A

Tags: ibm, ibm-midrange

After a power failure while the IPL was being done in D mode, when I connect the server to the power again, the code C100101A appears in the panel, and after a while the server restarts and code C100101A appears again, and it is stuck in this loop ... what should I do ?

Edit...

My as400 is a 9406-270

Comment: `what should I do?` - Open a support case with IBM. Seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C1xx 1xxx   Service Processor ROS IPL in progress

From
[IPL system reference code (SRC) finder](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzahb/rzahbiplsrcfinder.htm)

I assume as old as that machine is, you don't have IBM support anymore.  You might find some community support via the [midrange.com](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l) mailing list.

Comment: Yes, the computer is really old ( from 2001... )... Thank you, I will post a question in this mailing list!!!!!

Comment: @Alexandre, it would be very nice if you could reflect your findings here.

Comment: @PoC The solution was to replace the motherboard, since the service processor 'died'